# AppleScript — listen for mouse click?

Tags: applescript, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm brand new to Apple Script and trying to write a simple script that, while running, logs **a timestamp any time the mouse is clicked anywhere.**

How can I **detect/listen for mouse events,** and execute a command (logging a date-time) when they happen?

(This seems to me like a pretty basic thing to try to do, but I may be misunderstanding what AppleScript is for.)

Comment: I'm not sure one can state they are new to a programming/language, then go on to state a particular task should be "basic".  You would need to know the ins and outs of the language fairly well, and also what occurs at system level whenever the mouse is clicked, in order to have a sense of how achievable something is.  It's a lot more involved than you think, and AppleScript isn't a language designed for anything like this.  A shell script could do it, but I think it polls for events, which is not a good method.  Otherwise, C, Objective-C, or Swift are your main options.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse-clicks are events handled and distributed by the system. In order to capture them you'd need to set up an event monitor, but there are no hooks for that in vanilla AppleScript; the language isn't designed for it.

If you wanted to switch to AppleScriptObjC and create an application, you could certainly set up an event monitor of this sort (using something like `NSEvent's addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`. But I doubt AppleScript is the best language for it. At least, I can't think of a compelling reason to do this in AppleScript as opposed to writing a small cocoa app, and I anticipate a number of headaches trying to make the callback work correctly.